# Google BigQuery Python library is 2x as fast as the Node JS library for downloading results

Tags: javascript, python, google-bigquery

I've been doing a test to compare the speeds at which the Google BigQuery Python client library downloads query results compared to the Node JS library. It would seem that, out-of-the-box, the Python libraries download data about **twice as fast** as the Javascript Node JS client. Why is that so?

Below I provide the two tests, one in Python and one in Javascript.
I've selected the `usa_names` public dataset of BigQuery as an example.  The `usa_1910_current` table in this dataset is about 6 million rows and about `180Mb` in size.  I have a 200Mb fibre download link (for information about the last mile). The data, after being packed into a pandas dataframe, is about 1.1Gb (with Pandas overhead included).

**Python test**

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
import time
import pandas as pd

bq_client = bigquery.Client("mydata-1470162410749")

sql = """SELECT * FROM `bigquery-public-data.usa_names.usa_1910_current`"""

job_config = bigquery.QueryJobConfig()

start = time.time()
#---------------------------------------------------
query_job = bq_client.query(
    sql,
    location='US',
    job_config=job_config)  
#--------------------------------------------------- 
end = time.time()
query_time = end-start

start = time.time()
#---------------------------------------------------
rows = list(query_job.result(timeout=30))
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[list(x.values()) for x in rows], columns=list(rows[0].keys()))
#---------------------------------------------------    
end = time.time()

iteration_time = end-start
dataframe_size_mb = df.memory_usage(deep=True).sum() / 1024 ** 2
print("Size of the data in Mb: " + str(dataframe_size_mb) + " Mb")
print("Shape of the dataframe: " + str(df.shape))
print("Request time:", query_time)
print("Fetch time:", iteration_time)
```

**Node JS test**

```
// Import the Google Cloud client library
const {BigQuery} = require('@google-cloud/bigquery');
const moment = require('moment')

async function query() {

  const bigqueryClient = new BigQuery();
  const query = "SELECT * FROM `bigquery-public-data.usa_names.usa_1910_current`";
  const options = {
    query: query,
    location: 'US',
  };

  // Run the query as a job
  const [job] = await bigqueryClient.createQueryJob(options);
  console.log(`Job ${job.id} started.`);

  // Wait for the query to finish
  let startTime = moment.utc()
  console.log('Start: ', startTime.format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss"));
  const [rows] = await job.getQueryResults();
  let endTime = moment.utc()
  console.log('End: ', endTime.format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss"));
  console.log('Difference (s): ', endTime.diff(startTime) / 1000)
}

query();
```

### Python library test results with 180Mb of data:

- Size of the data in Mb: 1172.0694370269775 Mb
- Shape of the dataframe: (6028151, 5)
- Request time: 3.58441424369812
- Fetch time: **388.0966112613678** <-- This is **6.46 mins**

### Node JS library test results with 180Mb of data:

- Start:  2019-06-03 19:11:03
- End:  2019-06-03 19:24:12 <- About **13 mins**

For further reference, I also ran the tests against a 2Gb table...

### Python library test results with 2Gb of data:

- Size of the data in Mb: 3397.0339670181274 Mb
- Shape of the dataframe: (1278004, 21)
- Request time: 2.4991791248321533
- Fetch time: **867.7270500659943** <-- This is **14.45mins**

### Node JS library test results with 2Gb of data:

- Start:  2019-06-03 15:30:59
- End:  2019-06-03 16:02:49 <-- The difference is just below **31 mins**

Answer (score 1):

As I can see Node JS uses [pagination](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-bigquery/blob/master/src/dataset.ts#L331) to manage the datasets while Python with looks like  it brings the entire datasets and start to work with it.

This is maybe affecting the performance of the Node JS client library, my recommendation is to take a look at the source code of both clients and read constantly the Google Cloud Blog, where Google publishes sometimes tips and best practices to use their products, as an example this article: [Testing Cloud Pub/Sub clients to maximize streaming performance.](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/data-analytics/testing-cloud-pubsub-clients-to-maximize-streaming-performance)